# Очереди рассылки email

Tags: node.js, php

Кто реализовывал подсистему очередей сообщений, когда в системе скапливаются разного типа сообщения, которые нужно разослать клиенту?

Как можно проверить, получил ли пользователь сообщение на email?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?.. Ну, накапливаем мы сообщения, хоть в память, хоть в майскл, хоть в редис.. Алгоритм накопления - на усмотрение заказчика. Нужно разослать емейлы через ноду?.. Ок. [Например, вот таким вот инструментом, асинхронно пишем резалт в базу, если нужно.](http://www.nodemailer.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовать очередь можно по разному, как уже было сказано.

Получил или нет ваш клиент email-сообщение вы не сможете, если будете использовать для отправки обычный почтовый сервер. В логах увидите только, что сообщение было отправлено. Теоретически можете узнать, что оно попало в папку "Спам".

Если же вы хотите точно узнать, было ли **прочитано** ваше сообщение, следует использовать сервисы для транзакционной почты, типа http://mailhandler.ru или http://postmarkapp.com. С помощью их API, вы сможете получить события, связанные с каждым вашим email-сообщением, в том числе и событие OPENED, что означает, что email был прочитан.